# How to get array from ITK image without using loop?

Tags: c++, itk, simpleitk

Maybe have a function return a pointer or copy memory to a given pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SimpleITK::Image** has a lot of methods that return the pointer as you need:

https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1Image.html

you might want: **SimpleITK::Image::GetBufferAsVoid()**

or other ones ...

Answer (score 0):

`itk::Image`'s [`GetBufferPointer()`](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Image.html#aa6ce68e3fc18faf29b2cbb8dce2187b9) method is probably what you want.